# tor Ivp6 Cannot bind

Tags: bridge

I've been trying to get IVP6 running on my tor bridge, and ever since I've had this great idea it's been a Mount Kilimajaro vertical climb with me not getting much past the base of the
mountain.

I am installing on a Digital Ocean Droplet (Ubuntu 20.4). IVP6 has been enabled on the site.

Secondly I used the Tor Configator to set up the torrc file. Below is the file from Tor Configator, somewhat modified by me.

```
ORPort 6XXX
ORPort [2604:a880:400:d0::1998:a001]:auto
ExtORPort auto
SocksPort 0
BridgeRelay 1
Nickname 
ContactInfo 
ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 0.0.0.0:8XXX
Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
ExitPolicy reject6 *:*, reject *:*
RelayBandwidthRate 
RelayBandwidthBurst 
#AccountingStart month 1 00:00
#AccountingMax 1 GB
DisableDebuggerAttachment 0
ControlPort 9051
CookieAuthentication 1
```

Repeated error after many tries:

```
Dec 02 07:15:43.393 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9xxx
Dec 02 07:15:43.393 [notice] Opened Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9XXX
Dec 02 07:15:43.393 [notice] Opening OR listener on 0.0.0.0:6969
Dec 02 07:15:43.393 [notice] Opened OR listener on 0.0.0.0:6969
Dec 02 07:15:43.393 [notice] Opening OR listener on [2604:a880:400:d0::1998:a001]:0 <A port number was assigned here, came back as zero
Dec 02 07:15:43.393 [warn] Could not bind to 2604:a880:400:d0::1998:a001:0: Cannot assign requested address
Dec 02 07:15:43.393 [notice] Opening Extended OR listener on 127.0.0.1:0
Dec 02 07:15:43.393 [notice] Extended OR listener listening on port 4XXXX
Dec 02 07:15:43.393 [notice] Opened Extended OR listener on 127.0.0.1:4XXXX
Dec 02 07:15:43.393 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9XXX
Dec 02 07:15:43.393 [notice] Closing partially-constructed OR listener on 0.0.0.0:6XXX
Dec 02 07:15:43.393 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Extended OR listener on 127.0.0.1:4XXXX
Dec 02 07:15:43.393 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Dec 02 07:15:43.393 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

The IVP is the public address assigned by Digital Ocean to the Droplet. The range is from
a001 - a001 F

I've tried following online websites and I have learned that much of that information is or is
not trustable. Hard to know when you are new to Tor.

Any help would be appreciated, and thank you!!

Comment: Is your droplet's networking set up for IPv6? If you run the command `ip addr`, do you see your IPv6 address there?

Comment: Hi Steve thank you for your help Here's what ip addr says: 2. eth0

Comment: It doesn't look like your comment posted correctly. Can you edit your question and paste it there instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to setup IPv6 only relay then forget about it - it WILL NOT work. See [A Tor relay operators IPv6 HOWTO](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/IPv6RelayHowto) for more.

Specifically the above page says:

> There is currently no way of running an IPv6 only relay. Your relay
> will have to publish both an IPv4 and an IPv6 OR port. This limitation
> will go away but note that your relay will need to be able to make
> outgoing IPv4 connections for a foreseeable future.

The page mentions this issue tracker: [#5788: Add support for relays without an IPv4 address](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/5788)

Additionally, if I read the `tor` man page correctly, you can specify both (optional) IP address and numeric port for ORPort option or single value of `auto`. Therefore, your configuration entry:

```
ORPort [2604:a880:400:d0::1998:a001]:auto
```

is invalid. Your probably can do the following:

```
ORPort auto IPv6Only
```

to limit ORPort to IPv6 only and have automatic assignment.

Comment: I don't think this is an IPv6-only relay, as it's also listening on an IPv4 address (`ORPort 6XXX`).

Comment: If it has public IPv4 address assigned. And it is NOT apparent from attached logs that it has one.

Comment: The issue is that the relay is unable to bind to the given IPv6 address, which is unrelated to the server having (or not having) a public IPv4 address.

Comment: That's probably the second part of my answer. Apparently auto is interpreted as 0 and this is invalid port number. Hence bind fails.

Comment: I've tried ORPort with [IPv6]:auto and it worked on 0.4.3.7. Maybe it is older version with a bug?

Comment: `auto` works the same way for IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. It calls `bind()` with a port of 0, which means "any port". The kernel will then bind the socket to a non-zero port.

Comment: Every time I write one of these questions I feel like I need a law degree 'cuz there is always something  I miss or don't clarify very well. The 'relay' is an IVP4 BRIDGE with IVP6 access. Does that help?? BTW Thanks all for your help!! Much appreciated!

Comment: Ok FWIW - tor --version 0.4.4.6